# How to correctly implement the mapping protocol in Python?

Tags: python

I'm using python-spidermonkey, which internally uses PyMapping_Check to identify if the object being used as a global (in rt.new_context(global)) implements the mapping protocol. (This is basically a dictionary passed to python-spidermonkey so that javascript has limited access to python variables.)

There's no official definition I could find of the mapping protocol in Python, so I've been using trial and error to determine what's in it. Is there an official reference?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The [`collections.abc`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/collections.abc.html#collections-abstract-base-classes) module defines the interfaces for things like `Mapping`, `Sequence`, and so on.

By inheriting from the abstract base classes in that module, you get default implementations of some of the methods. So to be considered a `Mapping`, your class definition should look something like this:

```
class MyMapping(collections.abc.Mapping):
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        pass
    def __iter__(self):
        pass
    def __len__(self):
        pass
```

Inheriting from `Mapping` will get you 'free' implementations of most of `dict`'s useful methods:

- `__contains__`
- `keys`
- `items`
- `values`
- `get`
- `__eq__`
- `__ne__`

If these default method implementations are inefficient with your custom data structure, you can always override them with your own versions.

---

To be considered a `MutableMapping`, your class's interface should look like this:

```
class MyMutableMapping(collections.abc.MutableMapping):
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        pass
    def __setitem__(self, key, item):
        pass
    def __delitem__(self, key):
        pass
    def __iter__(self):
        pass
    def __len__(self):
        pass
```

Inheriting from `MutableMapping` gets you 'free' definitions of all of `Mapping`'s methods, plus:

- `pop`
- `popitem`
- `clear`
- `update`
- `setdefault`

---

If you're 'rolling your own' from scratch and don't want to use an abstract base class, you should probably try to define *all* of the above methods, if you want your class to be strictly Liskov-substitutable for `dict`.

Comment: This seems correct, thanks! I wish they had used the keyword mapping protocol anywhere on that page.

Comment: You can also use `collections.Mapping.register(MyMappingLikeClass)` if you know that you've implemented enough of the mapping protocol for your specific use, but not enough to pass the regular mapping checks.

Comment: @Blckknght: what are the "regular mapping checks"?

Comment: I believe the `__setitem__` signature should be `def __setitem__(self, item, value)` for MutabeMapping.

Comment: Should __iter__(self) return a iterator over (key,value) pairs, or only keys? Is the order important? I could not find these details in the documentation.