# What is a mapping object, according to dict type?

Tags: python, dictionary, mapping

The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict) lists 3 ways for creating a dict instance:

```
class dict(**kwarg)
class dict(mapping, **kwarg)
class dict(iterable, **kwarg)
```

What exactly is a *mapping* here?  What's the minimal interface required for `dict(mapping)` to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As usual, feel free to peruse the code :)

So, let's go into `Include/dictobject.h`:

```
132 /* PyDict_Merge updates/merges from a mapping object (an object that
133    supports PyMapping_Keys() and PyObject_GetItem()).  If override is true,
134    the last occurrence of a key wins, else the first.  The Python
135    dict.update(other) is equivalent to PyDict_Merge(dict, other, 1).
136 */
```

So we're looking for things that have `PyMapping_Keys` and `PyObject_GetItem`. Because we're lazy, we just use the search box in the python docs and find [the mappings protocol](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/mapping.html?highlight=mapping). So if your CPython PyObject follows that protocol, you're good to go.

Comment: Somewhat surprised this isn't documented more explicitly than a comment in the source code.  c-api mappings protocol is implementation detail, not actual language spec.

Comment: Is _is_ documented more explicitly in the [official glossary](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-mapping).

Answer (score 21):

From [the source code for CPython](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.7.2/Objects/dictobject.c#L2374-L2378), this comment:

```
/* We accept for the argument either a concrete dictionary object,
 * or an abstract "mapping" object.  For the former, we can do
 * things quite efficiently.  For the latter, we only require that
 * PyMapping_Keys() and PyObject_GetItem() be supported.
 */
```

So, "the minimal interface required for dict(mapping) to work" appears to be `.keys()` and `.__getitem__()`.

Example program:

```
class M:
    def keys(self):
        return [1,2,3]
    def __getitem__(self, x):
        return x*2

m = M()

d = dict(m)

assert d == {1:2, 2:4, 3:6}
```

Answer (score 7):

The [glossary](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-mapping) defines it as:

> A container object that supports arbitrary key lookups and implements
>   the methods specified in the [Mapping](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Mapping) or [MutableMapping](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.MutableMapping) abstract base
>   classes. Examples include [`dict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict), [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict),
>   [`collections.OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) and [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter).

So it looks like the minimal list of methods to meet the definition is `__getitem__`, `__iter__`, `__len__`, `__contains__`, `keys`, `items`, `values`, `get`, `__eq__`, and `__ne__`. Although I bet the dict constructor does not actually need all of those.

Comment: Actually you do not need to implement all of them. If you inherit from collections.abc.Mapping, and implement __getitem__, __iter__, __len__, then  __contains__, keys, items, values, get, __eq__, and __ne__ comes free. See documentation here: https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/collections.abc.html#collections-abstract-base-classes and see this answer which made me realize it. https://stackoverflow.com/a/19775773/6087087

Answer (score 4):

It seems that implementing only `keys` and `__getitem__` is sufficient.

```
>>> class mydict:
...     def keys(self):
...         return 'xyz'
...     def __getitem__(self, item):
...         return 'potato'
...     
>>> dict(mydict())
{'x': 'potato', 'y': 'potato', 'z': 'potato'}
```

Comment: still valid up to 3.6, also makes the object usable for `**` argument unpacking.

Answer (score -1):

It's the best answer for your question:

https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#typesmapping

It's the simplest example of mapping: `{}`

If you want to create a custom mapping type, you may inherit it from base `dict` and overwrite `__getitem__` magic method(it depends on your needs)

Comment: all `dict`ionaries are mappings but not all mappings are dictionaries - this question is asking about **what constitutes a mapping** not asking for an example.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen, so, where I told that all mappings are dicts?

Comment: from the link in your answer: "There is currently only one standard mapping type, the dictionary." so the only builtin mapping is `dict`, not at all that every mapping must be a dict.

Comment: `{}` is not the simplest example of mapping.  `{}` has all kinds of other crap on it