# Tuple to Dict :: TypeError: cannot convert dictionary update sequence element #0 to a sequence

Tags: python, dictionary

This works OK:

```
In [104]: i = [(1, 'a')]
In [105]: dict(i)
Out[105]: {1: 'a'}
```

It seems I have a list containing one tuple that I called the dict() function on and it returned a dictionary.

i has not changed due to the call:

```
In [114]: i
Out[114]: [(1, 'a')]
```

If I try this:

```
 In [108]: i = (1, 'a')
 In [109]: dict(i)
```

I get TypeError: cannot convert dictionary update sequence element #0 to a sequence.

I assume this is because a tuple is immutable. If true, I have not changed anything though, right?

In the working example above i is still just i.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From python documentation ([link](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict)):

> class dict(**kwarg)
>
> class dict(mapping, **kwarg)
>
> class dict(iterable,**kwarg)
>
> Return a new dictionary initialized from an optional positional argument and a possibly empty set of keyword arguments.
>
> If no positional argument is given, an empty dictionary is created. If
>   a positional argument is given and it is a mapping object, a
>   dictionary is created with the same key-value pairs as the mapping
>   object. Otherwise, the positional argument must be an iterable object.
>   Each item in the iterable must itself be an iterable with exactly two
>   objects. The first object of each item becomes a key in the new
>   dictionary, and the second object the corresponding value. If a key
>   occurs more than once, the last value for that key becomes the
>   corresponding value in the new dictionary.
>
> If keyword arguments are given, the keyword arguments and their values
>   are added to the dictionary created from the positional argument. If a
>   key being added is already present, the value from the keyword
>   argument replaces the value from the positional argument.

You are passing a tuple which is an iterable so python is iterating it trying to expand members in 2 (Key and Value) and failing because the members are not a 2 member iterable that can be assigned to Key and value.

Comment: That's my confusion. It seems a 2-tuple is a 2-member iterable as it has 2 members and can be iterated. Seems like it could just assign 1 => 'a'

Comment: "Each item in the iterable must itself be an iterable with exactly two objects." - You must pass an **iterable** of 2-member iterables. This outer iterable can contain a single 2-member iterable, but you can't just pass a single "naked" 2-member iterable.

Comment: OK so then I think we can say  "A tuple of 2-tuples satisfies the dict() function, but to simply have one "naked" - as you say - 2-tuple will not". (Unless that naked 2-tuple becomes clothed in a list).

Answer (score 4):

[`dict()`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html#dict) expects you to pass either a [mapping object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40667093/what-is-a-mapping-object-according-to-dict-type), or an iterable of key-value pairs (each of which must be a 2-element iterable).

A list of 2-tuples is the latter, a single 2-tuple is neither.

Comment: Thanks. I don't see how a 2-tuple would not work. It's an iterable with 2-elements and could be used for key : value. Do I need at least two tuples?

Comment: That's just not how `dict` was implemented. It's expecting an iterable of key-value pairs, not a single key-value pair.

Comment: You can give it a single key:value, but you have to wrap it in two layers of iterables - like you do in your first example in the question.

Comment: That seems to be the key - wrap it so there are two layers of iterables.

Answer (score 2):

`dict` expects a sequence of sequences, so when you just give it a one dimensional sequence it fails.  You can use tuples instead of lists.

```
d = dict(((1, 1), (2, 2)))
```

gives us

```
{1: 1, 2: 2}
```

Comment: tks. That actually fails for me: TypeError: dict expected at most 1 arguments, got 2 w/python 2 or 3.

Comment: Needs more brackets: `d = dict(((1, 1), (2, 2)))` - the outermost set are the function call brackets.

Comment: Great.Slightly confusing though is why a 2-tuple wrapped in a tuple does not work. But I think we're in the weeds now and it's how it was implemented as above.

Comment: I suspect your tuple in a tuple looks something like `((1, 1))`. This actually evaluates to `(1, 1)` for the same reason `(1/2)` isn't a tuple. A tuple of length one has a trailing comma `((1, 1),)`.