# why **os.environ works in python?

Tags: python

When defining a function, * means to collect parameters, and ** means to collect keyword parameters.

```
env = {**os.environ}
```

os.environ is not a dict,why the above code works?

Comment: it has `.keys()`, `.items()`, `__getitem__`, etc. similar to dictionary so it can behave like dictionary.

Comment: in some situations `**` means `"collect keyword parameters"` but in other situations it means `"unpack dictionary"`

Comment: Related: [What is a mapping object, according to dict type?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40667093/674039)

Comment: Moreover: [Class that acts as mapping for **unpacking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8601268/class-that-acts-as-mapping-for-unpacking)

Answer (score 2):

Although `**` is typically used on dictionaries, it allows you to unpack any `Mapping`.

Note that:

```
import os
from typing import Mapping

print(isinstance(os.environ, Mapping))
```

Prints:

```
True
```

Similarly, `*` allows you to unpack any iterable.

Comment: You should probably demonstrate with [`collections.abc.Mapping`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.Mapping) instead.  `typing.Mapping` is deprecated. Also, I think both dupe-hammering _and_ answering together is a bit weird.

Comment: There's nothing against providing an answer to a question that's a dupe - it's a dupe, so it should get closed, but I figured giving OP a basic answer might help them. Not sure how that's weird.

Comment: It’s explained why that’s discouraged here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/286072/674039

Comment: The argument made there is fair - I wasn't hunting for upvotes (and in fact assumed I wouldn't get one), in retrospect should have provided the info in a comment (the reason I didn't was because I figured a short bit of code would be more helpful). Not so much weird as undesirable for good reason.